# How to keep only strings in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains characteristics of many companies.
My problem is that in the column 'Facility Name', I found out that there are some rows which have a float value, thus I would like to delete them. In order to do so I used the following line of code which does not seem to work:

```
df = df[isinstance(df['Facility Name'], str)]
```

Any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close. This should work:

Python 2.x:

```
df = df[df['Facility Name'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, basestring))]
```

Python 3.x:

```
df = df[df['Facility Name'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (str, bytes)))]
```

Below is some Python 3.x code so you can see how it works:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Facility Name': [1, 0, None, 'Yes', 'No', 'Maybe So', b'what', np.nan, np.inf]})                                                         

In [4]: df                                                                                                                                                           
Out[4]: 
  Facility Name
0             1
1             0
2          None
3           Yes
4            No
5      Maybe So
6       b'what'
7           NaN
8           inf

In [5]: df[df['Facility Name'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]                                                                                                  
Out[5]: 
  Facility Name
3           Yes
4            No
5      Maybe So

In [6]: df[df['Facility Name'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (str, bytes)))]                                                                                         
Out[6]: 
  Facility Name
3           Yes
4            No
5      Maybe So
6       b'what'
```

Comment: You are missing one parenthesis at the end I think.

Comment: @Outcast, indeed.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Also, you could add the correct answer for Python 3.x which is with `str` instead of `basestring`, if I am not missing something ;)

Comment: You're right, needed an example in Python 3.x.  I added bytes as another type just in case those are in the field.