# keep only strings in a dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In this df I want only to keep the strings in each row and deleate everything else

```
     Values          
0   99;3;;Sicherheitstür (0SS4.2) bei Anfang Boxen...
1   100;3;;Sicherheitstür (0SS4.2) bei Anfang Boxe...
3   145;3;;Sicherheitstür (0SS3b.5) bei Einspeisef...
4   95;3;;Sicherheitstür (0SS3b.5) vor Boxen unten...
5   96;3;;Sicherheitstür (0SS3b.5) vor Boxen unten...
6   30;3;;Anlage ausgeschaltet (Schlüsselschalter ...
7   37;3;;Sicherheitsbereich 5 (Paketierung) ausge...
```

[I found this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33845956/12267139)

but got a Syntax error

```
  File "<ipython-input-17-a2c397c4c493>", line 1
    df = df[df['Value'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, basestring)]
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: df = df[df['Value'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))] should work

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 use `str` instead `basestring`:

```
 df = df[df['Value'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

If want first extract all strings values and then count:

```
s = df['Values'].str.extractall('([a-zA-Z]+)')[0].value_counts()
print (s)
SS                    5
Sicherheitstur        5
b                     3
bei                   3
Boxen                 3
unten                 2
Anfang                2
vor                   2
ausge                 1
Boxe                  1
Anlage                1
Sicherheitsbereich    1
Einspeisef            1
ausgeschaltet         1
Paketierung           1
Schlusselschalter     1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```